# creates a selectbox to load data without refreshing the page

Tags: asp.net, jquery-selectbox

`asp.net` creates a selectbox to load data without refreshing the page When selecting the value in the selectbox, it will load the corresponding content below.

Comment: for that you have to use `ajax` and `webservices` refer this [simple example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002744/How-to-Bind-a-HTML-Dropdown-List-with-Web-Services)

Comment: For example, now I choose a department then it will show a select list of employees of that department how to do? Can you help me? Thank you very much <3